# How to add loading page until webpage loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am designing a web page for my school containing high resolution images and videos. So, I need Js/jquery  code for adding a loading page until the whole web page loads.

Comment: So what is the problem here?

Comment: But what is your problem?

Comment: This is just me, but I think we should encourage new users not scare them away.

Comment: Sorry, i would follow you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a gimme-the-codez-question. Questions like these have no lasting value. Instead try to get this working yourself, and come back here when you run into a problem that you can not solve, and that is not answered by searching on StackOverflow. Please read the help center.

Comment: @stepanian New users, like any user, need to learn how to ask high-quality questions. This question is very very very low quality. Tbh by answering such questions you encourage users to ask more low-quality answers, which hurts this site. If downvoting a question or closing a question is not allowed because it scares an user away, then that will drive away the people that actually answer good questions, which will hurt the site more in the long run. I think you have vtc power at your rep level, so use it.

Comment: @Sumurai8 "low quality"? This is not a competition. It is a forum where more experienced developers help others. No one is here to prove anything. It seems like you or someone who thinks like you just down voted my response, which is ironic because it helped the OP and I'm sure will help others.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum, it's a Q&A site. Inexperienced developers are perfectly able to write high-quality questions about beginner problems. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the Stack Overflow checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648). This question is not high-quality, because it's too broad. OP outlines a very very vague requirement, which means that a wide range of solutions apply. and the best solution can only be chosen based on unwritten context. Instead OP should have tried to solve the problem themselves, and ask a question with...

Comment: ...an [MCVE](/help/mcve), problem description and expected behaviour when they really got stuck. The question is unlikely to help anyone, because it matches too many problems, and thus is unlikely to match the problem of anyone who comes here through google.

Comment: We agree to disagree.

Comment: @Sumurai8 the same user here you're discouraging above in comments, wanna ask feedback on how is my new question quality as here (btw its 3y ago, since then I craft my architecture mostly so is used less by me): https://stackoverflow.com/q/55701200/4481187

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is put the images in a hidden div and have another div display whatever you want while the images are loading. Once loaded, you can hide the temp div and show the main div. You can use jQuery for this. There are jQuery plugins for loading completion notifications.

Comment: This helped, but sorry i cant vote 'cause I am new here.

Comment: No worries my friend :)

Comment: Ok :-) (but did you noticed that your smiley don't have nose above!)