# How to generate Queues per user inside celery?

Tags: django, redis, rabbitmq, celery

So I'm trying to move blocking stuff from web request as background tasks and leveraging queue. I'm also new to messaging and pub/sub. Users push there data and it is processed and later users are notified about that. I made a celery setup for this and found that it doesn't satisfy my use case for having private queue for every user for their own tasks.

I tried specifying creation of missing queues and during worker spawning (sending queue names comma separated) and also listing them in queues settings as stated in previous answers over internet for "dynamic queue creation with celery". It creates the queues, but doesn't when I specify different queue name than specified names in settings and command line. The solution is to spawn more workers with queue names which doesn't satisfy the use case as there will be millions of data processing requests.

I've found that python-rq has Queue object initialization with its name, which I think creates new queue. If it does, will shifting to RQ will be right?

```
redis_conn = Redis()
q = Queue('some_queue', connection=redis_conn)
```

What I want is per user queue for their own tasks in the background. I don't see any solutions online for creating dynamic queues (without specifying in command line the queue name or in settings) in celery. python-rq seems having that solution. My trade-off in that will be to move to redis from RabbitMQ and celry.

Is there a way to really do per user queues in celery? If yes, please list steps. Or is this design pattern just not right? Will pubsub satisfy the use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Celery worker consumes only from queues defined by [`task_queues`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_queues) setting or given on command line with [`-Q`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-q) option. However, this can be changed dynamically, either from command line or from code. Just be sure to have [`task_create_missing_queues`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_create_missing_queues) enabled in the settings (which is the default), so that new queues are automatically created when you start consuming from them.

So, before you send the task for given user, you have to instruct the workers to start consuming from the user's queue. This can be achieved either from command line by using [`add_consumer`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#std:control-add_consumer) control command, or from the code using [`app.control.add_consumer()`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Control.add_consumer) method. These operations are idemponent so if the worker already consumes from the queue, nothing happens. If the queue doesn't yet exist, it's created automatically.

Comment: This solved my problem @Tomáš Linhart. I am now able to add queues after grabbing the worker control. Will it now go like this... the worker will use concurrency to process jobs from the queues? So do I need to increase workers count or concurrency settings? I'm going to have millions of requests from users for data processing.

Comment: Yeah, the concurrency settings apply normally here. You will have to experiment with the settings to achieve the best performance. Also, take a look at [autoscaling](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#autoscaling) options.

Comment: It is going to have fun experimenting that thing. Well, thank you @Tomáš Linhart for helping with this.